# Java IOStream Arrays JFrame

Tags: java, arrays, jframe, iostream

I have to create a CD inventory program for my first Java class.  The book is poorly written and extremely verbose.  I have created 4 frames to handle each requirement of the assignment.  But the book doesn't explain how to write arrays to a .dat file.  If I could get an idea of how to add data to an array from my TextFields then write to a .dat file I could stumble through the rest.  Here is what I have so far.  How do I take my JTextFields from my Add CD listener and write to a .dat file so I can view it later.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.SecurityException;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.FormatterClosedException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;



class CDinventoryItem extends JFrame implements Comparable <CDinventoryItem> {

    private String sPtitle;
    private String genreCD;
    private int iPitemNumber;
    private int iPnumberofUnits;
    private double dPunitPrice;
    private double dEvalue;
    private JFrame frame2= new JFrame();
    private JFrame frame3= new JFrame();
    private JFrame frame4= new JFrame();
    private JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panel5 = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panel6 = new JPanel();
    private JLabel[] label = new JLabel[20];
    private JTextField titleField;
    private JTextField itemNField;
    private JTextField numofunitsField;
    private JTextField priceField;
    private JButton next;
    private JButton prev;
    private JButton addCD = new JButton ("Add CD");
    private JButton save = new JButton ("Save");
    private JButton delete;
    private JButton modify;
    private JButton search = new JButton ("Search for CD");
    private JButton mainmenu;
    private JButton displayCD = new JButton ("Display Inventory");
    private CDinventoryItem [] inven;
    private DataOutputStream outFile;
    private DataInputStream inputFile;



    public CDinventoryItem (String title, int itemNumber, int numberofUnits, 
    double unitPrice, String genre){

            sPtitle = title;
            iPitemNumber = itemNumber;
            iPnumberofUnits = numberofUnits;
            dPunitPrice = unitPrice;
            genreCD = genre;


        for(int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
        label[i] = new JLabel();
        }

        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel1.add(label[0]);
        Icon bug = new ImageIcon( getClass().getResource( "mylogo.JPG" ) );
        label[0].setIcon( bug );
        label[0].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));

        panel1.add(label[1]);
        label[1].setText("Press button to choose option:");
        label[1].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 50));


        panel1.add(panel2);
        panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 50));
        ButtonListerner inputNewCD = new ButtonListerner();
        panel2.add(addCD);
        addCD.addActionListener(inputNewCD);
        ButtonListerner searchCD = new ButtonListerner();
        panel2.add(search);
        search.addActionListener(searchCD);

        ButtonListerner display = new ButtonListerner();
        panel2.add(displayCD);
        displayCD.addActionListener(display);

        setContentPane(panel1);

    }


    private class ButtonListerner implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent event) {


        if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Add CD"))
        {
            frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
            frame2.setLocation(525,100);
            frame2.setSize(425, 425);
            frame2.setVisible( true );


            frame2.add(panel3);

            panel3.add(label[0]);

            panel3.add(label[2]);
            label[2].setText("Enter title of CD:");
            label[2].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));

            JTextField titleText = new JTextField(20);
            panel3.add (titleText);
            sPtitle.equals(titleText);
            label[2].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 25));

            panel3.add(label[3]);
            label[3].setText("Enter number of CDs:");

            JTextField numCDText = new JTextField(5);
            panel3.add(numCDText);
            label[3].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(275, 25));

            panel3.add(label[4]);
            label[4].setText("Enter price of CD:");
            JTextField priceCDText = new JTextField(6);
            panel3.add(priceCDText);

            label[4].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(274, 25));

            panel3.add(label[5]);
            label[5].setText("Pick genre:");
            String stringBox[] = {"Drama","Action","Comedy"};
            JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(stringBox);
            comboBox.setEditable(false);
            panel3.add(comboBox);

            panel3.add(save);

}

        if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Search for CD")){


            frame3.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
            frame3.setLocation(100,525);
            frame3.setSize(425, 425);
            frame3.setVisible( true );

            frame3.add(panel4);

            panel4.add(label[0]);

            panel4.add(label[6]);
            label[6].setText("Enter name of CD you want to search for:");
            JTextField searchName = new JTextField(20);
            panel4.add(searchName);

            panel4.add(label[7]);
            label[7].setText("Or search by genre:");
            JCheckBox checkB1 = new JCheckBox("Drama");
            JCheckBox checkB2 = new JCheckBox("Action");
            JCheckBox checkB3 = new JCheckBox("Comedy");
            panel4.add(checkB1);
            panel4.add(checkB2);
            panel4.add(checkB3);


        }

        if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Display Inventory")){

            frame4.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
            frame4.setLocation(525,525);
            frame4.setSize(425, 425);
            frame4.setVisible( true );

            frame4.add(panel5);

            panel5.add(label[0]);

            panel5.add(label[8]);
            label[8].setText("List of CDs:");

        }

        if (event.getActionCommand().equals("Save")){

            String dataFile = "inventory.dat";

            try{
            outFile = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(dataFile)));
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException ){

            }

        }
}}

    public int compareTo(CDinventoryItem otherItem) {
    return this.sPtitle.compareTo(otherItem.getTitle());
}

@Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return sPtitle;
}

}


public class CDinventoryprogram {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Welcome to my CD inventory program!!"
,  "Inventory", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    CDinventoryItem initem = new CDinventoryItem ("", 0, 0, 0.0,"" );
    initem.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
    initem.setLocation(100,100);
    initem.setSize(425, 425);
    initem.setVisible( true );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the method ButtonListerner.actionPerformed(), when the Add CD button is pressed (checked by event.getActionCommand().equals("Add CD")), you are creating a local text field:

```
JTextField titleText = new JTextField(20);
panel3.add (titleText);
sPtitle.equals(titleText);
label[2].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 25));

panel3.add(label[3]);
label[3].setText("Enter number of CDs:");

JTextField numCDText = new JTextField(5);
panel3.add(numCDText);
label[3].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(275, 25));
...
```

The first thing you need to do is use the one in the outer class (so you can get the values later):

```
titleField = new JTextField(20);
panel3.add (titleField);
sPtitle.equals(titleField);
label[2].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 25));

panel3.add(label[3]);
label[3].setText("Enter number of CDs:");

itemNField = new JTextField(5);
panel3.add(itemNField);
label[3].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(275, 25));
...
```

After this, when Save button is clicked, now your fields will hold the user input, so you can now get those values:

```
String title = titleField.getText();
...
```

Now to write to a file, you need to use an OutputStream. There are many OutputStream subclasses, each one has it's own use. BufferedWriter is for writing text, DataOutputStream is for writing binary data, you should not use both together like you are doing now. Assuming you want to write binary data, you can do this:

```
try {
    outFile = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dataFile));

    outFile.writeUTF(titleField.getText());

    // convert string to int
    int itemN = Integer.parseInt(itemNField.getText());
    outFile.writeInt(itemN);

    outFile.flush();
    outFile.close();
}
catch(IOException error) {
    error.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note: To keep things simple, I didn't added proper error handling (the outFile.close() should be in a finally statement).

Comment: The IOStream example I think I understand.  SHould it be in the Add CD action method?  Or create another action method for Save?  I assume yes, because you are saying I need it to be seen by the outer class.  Which brings me to my second question. It looks lie you just copied and pasted what I have and said I needed to do "this".  I am confused, how are you showing how to take those textfield values and pass them to the outerclass variables?

Comment: Are you saying something like this?  sPtitle = titleText.getText();

Comment: I didn't just copied, I did changes to show what was wrong. The file write must happen after the Save button get clicked (the same place you were trying) or it save the file before the user fill the fields.

Comment: Yes, sorry I see what you did.  It works.  Your awesome.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to be a nit-picker, but this:

```
class CDinventoryItem extends JFrame implements Comparable <CDinventoryItem>
```

has a "God" class anti-pattern design smell to it.  You are asking it to be a CDinventoryItem, to hold a collection of CDinventoryItems, to display this collection of items in a GUI and to be the root container of that GUI, and now to output that information to disk.  In other words you are asking this poor class to do too much.

Before even thinking about creating a GUI to display this information or writing code to output anything to a file, you need to seriously refactor it.

I recommend in the least you consider doing this:

1)  Create a class CDInventoryItem that's Comparable, and has fields to hold this information -- String title, int itemNumber, int numberofUnits, double unitPrice, String genre -- and that's it.

2)  Create another class for manipulating a collection of the above with an add method, a remove method, a listAll() method, a sort method, a search method, an int to refer to the current CDInventoryItem in the collection and a getter method to obtain it the current item, a method to get the next() and the previous() items, and to advance or decrement this int index,...

3)  A class for IO support for reading and writing CDInventoryItems to and from a file, perhaps using Serialization (then CDInventoryItem should be serializable).

4)  And then and only then should you start the GUI portion of your program. The GUI should use the classes above as its underlying logic.

If you do this, your coding will go along much more smoothly. If not, you may have a ton  of horrendous debugging ahead of you.

Comment: I have a program that does just that.  I started over due to the various things the class required.  I figured starting over was my best option.  You advice is the most I have gotten since this class started.  They are asking all this in an intro to java class, with a crappy textbook to learn from.

Comment: Please don't blame the "crappy" text book.  What with all the tutorials and resources available on line, the only limits to your learning are your efforts, not the textbook or the teacher.

Comment: I have put tons of effort into this.  Sorry buddy but the book IS crappy.  C++ was way easier than this.  I have looked at tons of reference material, tutorials, video tutorials...  All have been overly verbose and relating to something which wasn't exactly what I needed.  I have a 95 in the class and could not turn in my final project and still pass.  Your "help" reminds me of the whole experience I have had with java.  Long on what I am doing wrong and short on solutions.

Comment: I sure you are trying, but regardless, there is so much information out there that if you find one resource not to your liking, you are sure to find another that is better suited to you. If not, then the problem can't be that the entire internet has nothing but worthless information on Java.  Regardless, you are far better served in this forum doing less complaining about your book and more discussion about your problem at hand.  But up to you. And regarding "short on solutions", the solution is to refactor your code.  It would be pointless to try to fix it.

Comment: I agree that his CDinventoryItem class is doing too much, but I think he is more worried with learing the language than writing a clean code right now.

Comment: Perhaps, but he must do at least a minimal refactoring.  Right now, his JFrame is holding a collection of JFrames and displaying them in a JFrame.  At the very least he should create a CDItem class.  Then if he wants to dump the rest of the code into his GUI, the problem won't be so egregious.  But even this is only a short-term concern as his major long-term problem is the "whatever..." attitude. If he can fix this, he has potential, but if not...